# Shopping Cart provider ionic 2

Tags: angular, ionic2

I'm trying to build a little shopping cart with ionic 2. My problem is that I don't how to populate my provider with the elements I have in a specific array. 
This is my code :

```
//cart.ts

myFunction(index:number){
 this.cartItems.push({1:this.people[index].name.first, 2:this.people[index].qty});
 this.cartService.add()
 //don't know what to do 


 cart-service.ts

add(){
 //I want to pass my cartItems array here to use it in another page
}
```

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

...if I understand your question correctly:

So you have your array `cartItems` in your component, you can pass it with your method:

```
this.cartService.add(this.cartItems) // add your array as parameter
```

Then in your **service**:

```
let items = []; // declare an Array

add(items) {
   this.items = items; // populate the array
}
```

Comment: thank you, I've tried this, but I still have an error : property items does not exist ... But I have declared items !

Comment: Hmm, could you recreate the issue in a plunker? This doesn't seem to demand too much code. I'm happy to help, but it's quite difficult with so little code to go on. I'm not really sure what's going on in that `myFunction`, when is it called and you are pushing static content to your array, why? :)

Comment: ok, my bad ! Your solution work, but I have problems with the local storage, I think it's another issue...

Comment: Yes, seems like it then... Hmm, that issue does not really go in the frames for this question, so you should probably think of posting a new question if you do not get the issue solved! If your original question was solved by my answer, would you kindly accept the answer, thanks! :)